# Find the expressions for the given binary strings and tertiary strings:

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Find mathematical expressions for each of the followings:

1. The number of ternary strings (strings of 0s, 1s and 2s) of length 10.
2. The number of strings of 5 lower case letters (a-z) that do no contain any letter twice
   or more.
3. The number of binary strings of length 100 that contain at most two 1s.
4. The number of ternary strings of length 10 (strings of 0s, 1s and 2s) containing exactly
   two 1s and exactly three 2s.

For number 1 I did S={0,1,2}

For number 2,3 and 4 I could not try as I cannot understand the question. My understanding of binary strings and ternary strings is very poor. Any help to get the mathematical expressions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

1. For each digit you have three choices, so $3^{10}=59049$.
2. For the first letter 26 choices, for the second 25, ..., for the fifth 22, so $26\cdot25\cdot24\cdot23\cdot22=7893600$.
3. There are ${100\choose0}=1$ possibilities with no 1s, ${100\choose1}=100$ with one 1, and ${100\choose2}=4950$ with two 1s. So $1+100+4950=5051$ in total.
4. There are ${10\choose2}=45$ ways of picking positions for the two 1s, and in each case ${8\choose3}=56$ ways of picking positions for the three 2s. The remaining positions must be filled by 0s. So $45\cdot56=2520$ in total.